# When I minify css or js, why isn't it all on one line?

Tags: javascript, css, minify

I understand that minifying tries to reduce file size by removing whitespace characters. Sometimes things end up on one line, but more often than not, there are multiple lines. I noticed that line breaks happen wherever spaces occur. Wouldn't it be better just to have it all on one line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we have newlines in minified JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193851/why-do-we-have-newlines-in-minified-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of sample code and information about how the minification is being performed, my best guess would be: Whatever you are using to view the code is performing word wrapping and there aren't any real new lines in there.

Comment: One error i've had with dreamweaver a few years back was it would truncate lines that were too long (not even wrap) and if you tried to save it your document would get damaged.

Answer (score 3):

Well with JavaScript, a line break can imply the end of a statement (in place of the `;`).  So putting it all on one line could cause issues with the code functioning correctly.

I would guess that it depends on the minimizer you are using, but that could be one reason.  I would think the minimizer would try and account for this and put in semicolons where it can, but this ability could vary wildly between them.

Comment: if the line break is the replacement of semicolon ";", so a file with a thousand line breaks and a file with a thousand semicolons have the same size, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yuicompressor-maven-plugin, you may face this issue. The YUI compressor plugin has an option [linebreakpos](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html#linebreakpos) for which the default value is zero. If you read the description about how this option is used by the original YUI compressor library at [this page](http://www.julienlecomte.net/yuicompressor/README), you'll notice that a value of zero for this value means that a newline will be emitted after CSS rule or a semi-colon in javascript.

Fortunately, having a look at the [implementation](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/html5/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.2/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/CssCompressor.java?rev=920) suggests an easy work-around. Just specify any value less than 0 and you should be good to go.