# Why do we have newlines in minified JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, minify

I know about a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118776/when-i-minify-css-or-js-why-isnt-it-all-on-one-line) but it is a *tiny* bit off from what I am asking here, so *please* don't `flag` it as a duplicate.

When you see the [production version of jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js), why is there a newline after a while? I downloaded a copy and deleted all the newlines (apart from the licence) and it still worked. (I ran the **entire** unit test suite against my changes on Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera.)

[image: The problem. In Google Chrome's "view source"]

I know three newlines (not counting the license) is not going to slow it down a lot, but still, doesn't every tiny bit help?

I have assigned myself a small challenge, to squeeze every little bit of performance out of my JavaScript code.

Comment: Can you include the relevant lines?

Comment: @JamesMontagne what do you mean by that? of jQuery?

Comment: You ran the **entire** unit test suite against your changes?

Comment: @AnishGupta what he means is, you said "and it still worked". How can you be sure that *everything* still works? Did you run the unit tests?

Comment: Is your question specifically about the jQuery production library, or in general? FWIW, jQuery 1.7.2's line lengths are 32412 and 32770 each, so this _almost_ looks like a case of staying below 2^15 characters.

Comment: I guess that answers my question. :) The unit tests are here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/test

Comment: @Phrogz is right; Matt's answer explains it.

Comment: Why the reversal of an upvote? can you comment even?

Comment: @mgnoonan I did and it works.

Comment: @AnishGupta in *all* the browsers? JavaScript is tricky, as you have to run the tests in each specific browser you want to support, in order to test each JS implementation.

Comment: @mgnoonan FF and Chrome works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[jQuery currently use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608079/which-tools-does-jquery-use-to-compress-its-source-code) UglifyJS to minify their source code. In [their build script](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/build/uglify.js), they [specifically set](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/build/uglify.js#L19) the `max_line_length` directive to be `32 * 1024`:

The [documentation for UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) has this to say on the `max-line-len` directive;

> `--max-line-len` (default 32K characters) — add a newline after around 32K characters. I’ve seen both FF and Chrome croak when all the code was on a single line of around 670K. Pass –max-line-len 0 to disable this safety feature.

Comment: @AnishGupta what don't you get? They WANT the newlines. They configured their minify script so it would PUT the newlines there.

Comment: @AnishGupta because like Matt and others said, lines that are too longs can cause problems in certain browsers.

Comment: @AnishGupta glad you do :) Don't forget to consider accepting Matt's answer as the answer to your question if it helped you

Comment: Is this true for the most recent version of FF and Chrome?

Answer (score 15):

To cite the [Closure Compiler FAQ](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#linefeeds):

> The Closure Compiler intentionally adds line breaks every 500
>   characters or so. Firewalls and proxies sometimes corrupt or ignore
>   large JavaScript files with very long lines. Adding line breaks every
>   500 characters prevents this problem. Removing the line breaks has no
>   effect on a script's semantics. The impact on code size is small, and
>   the Compiler optimizes line break placement so that the code size
>   penalty is even smaller when files are gzipped.

This is relevant to any minification programs in general.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't know that. EDIT: Weird, I written this a while ago but it is only showing up now???

Comment: The message must've been stuck between the firewall and proxy.

Comment: Never knew firewalls and proxies could be so stupid. PBFAP. Also, does anyone know of an example? I'm really skeptical that someone could write a firewall so bad that it corrupts files (and get paid from people still using it).

Answer (score 5):

The lines (excluding the license) are all around 30k characters in length. It could be to avoid bugs where some Javascript parsers die on extremely long lines. This probably won't happen on today's browsers but maybe some older or more obscure ones have such limits.

---

*(Old answer below, which might also be applicable, just not in this case)*

This might be because [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html), a popular Javascript minifier will retain line feeds in the output under certain conditions. This is because in Javascript line feeds *are* significant if you leave out semicolons, for example. The documentation says:

> It is more conservative in omitting linefeeds, because linefeeds are sometimes treated as semicolons. A linefeed is not omitted if it precedes a non-ASCII character or an ASCII letter or digit or one of these characters:
>
> ```
> \ $ _ { [ ( + -
> ```
>
> and if it follows a non-ASCII character or an ASCII letter or digit or one of these characters:
>
> ```
> \ $ _ } ] ) + - " '
> ```

Other minifiers might have similar rules.

So this is mostly a precaution against accidentally removing a line feed that may be necessary, syntax-wise. The last thing you want is that your minified JS won't work anymore because the minifier destroyed its semantics.

Regarding *»I know three newlines (not counting the license) is not going to slow it down a lot, but still, doesn't every tiny bit help?«*: When your server uses gzip compression the difference will likely be moot anyway.

Comment: But why doesn't jQuery delete the newlines in the production version

Comment: These rules don't seem to be relevant in where [jQuery 1.7.2.min is split](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js); the first is between `G=function(` and `a)` and the second is between `var a=f` and `.clean(arguments);`

Comment: Why should they? The production version will most likely be automatically generated without a human looking over it.

Comment: @Joey As I said in the answer. Every little helps.